# Override Custom Theme Layout File with one in Module?

Tags: magento2, layout

I have a custom layout file `mytheme/default/magento_theme/layout/custom_cms_name.xml`

I need to override with a theme file from my custom module:

```
/companyname/modulename/frontend/layout/
```

I tested and `"/companyname/modulename/frontend/layout/cms_page_view_id_idhere.xml"` works so I know the module is working but `/companyname/modulename/frontend/layout/custom_cms_name.xml does not work.`

What naming convention can I use within my module to override custom layout form my theme ??

Answer (score 0):

I think your path worng .You are missing **`view folder`**.For Example Check below

Your path is :-

**`/companyname/modulename/frontend/layout/custom_cms_name.xml`**

instand of :-

**`/companyname/modulename/view/frontend/layout/custom_cms_name.xml`**

And finally you test your xml file like this :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Companyname\Modulename\Block\Post" name="brand.list" template="Companyname_Modulename::yourfilename.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

And Then run Below commands :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```